# How to make input range with two values, from and to

Tags: html, html-input

I want a html input with two values. like from value & to value. 
something like this:

[image]

if the value is showed in the bar is much appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: https://www.google.nl/search?q=html+number+slider+with+two+thumbs+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: https://www.google.nl/search?q=range+slider+two+thumbs+html+css+site:stackoverflow.co

Comment: I was looking for something without libraries, btw, thanks